# Extraer en variable javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `div` que me imprime en moneda todos los productos que voy añadiendo y queria darle formato, pero creo que si no saco esta función en un variable no puedo hacerlo.

**Esto es lo que me muestra el total de todo lo que añado**

```
var total = 0;

var miListaDeConceptos = [{
    "concepto": "Contenedor 20 pies",
    "precio": 20000,
    "Metros": "50"
  },
  {
    "concepto": "Contenedor 40 pies",
    "precio": 30000,
    "Metros": "100 "
  }
];


function pintaContenedor(x, el) {
  document.getElementById('nadaSeleccionado').style.display = 'none';
  //Valido si esta activado o no
  let ternariaVal = ($(x).is(':checked') ? functionPoner(x, el) : functionQuitar(x, el));
}

function functionQuitar(x, el) {
  var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[el];
  let elegido = '#' + el;
  total = total - elemento.precio;
  $(elegido).remove();
  mostrarTotal();
}

function functionPoner(x, el) {
  var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[el];
  $("#ContenedorElegido").append('<div id="' + el + '" class="col-12 listado" data-id="" data-precio="' + elemento.precio + '">' + elemento.concepto + '<span class="pull-right">' + elemento.precio + ',00 €</span><div>Metros:<span class="pull-right">' + elemento.Metros + 'm<sup>2</sup></span></div></div>');
  total += elemento.precio;
  mostrarTotal();
}

function mostrarTotal() {
  $("#htmlTotal").html('<div id="div_total"><span class="palab-total">TOTAL: </span><span class="palab-total2">' + total + ',00 €</span><div></div></div>');
}
```

**desde aquí pinto el contenedor**

```
<div class="pruebacheks">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cocina=[]" id="20pies" onchange="pintaContenedor(this,0);" />
      <label for="20pies" class="corrigeImgContenedor2"><img src="images/svg/20pies.png" alt="" class="img-fluid corrigeImgContenedor"></label>
      <h4>Módulo de 20 pies</h4>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cocina=[]" id="40pies" onchange="pintaContenedor(this,1);" />
      <label for="40pies" class="corrigeImgContenedor2"><img src="images/svg/20pies.png" alt="" class="img-fluid corrigeImgContenedor"></label>
      <h4>Módulo de 40 pies</h4>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Aquí muestro el total**

```
<div id="htmlTotal">
  <div id="div_total"><span class="palab-total">TOTAL: </span><span class="palab-total2">0,00 €</span><div>
</div>
```

**Lo intento así pero sin éxito**

```
const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
})
console.log(formatterEuro.format(mostrarTotal));
```

Comment: Ojo que en `console.log(formatterEuro.format(mostrarTotal));` le estás pasando como parámetro a format `mostrarTotal`, esto es el nombre de la función, no el resultado de la función. Para pasarle el resultado de la función tendrás que ponerle paréntesis: `console.log(formatterEuro.format(mostrarTotal()));` Y además la funcion mostrarTotal, no devuelve nada, no se si te estás liando con la variable `total` y la función `mostrarTotal`. ¿Podrías añadir el código donde se declara la variable `total`?

Comment: Hola @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA ya te añadi más código!

Comment: A mi me parece que simplemente tendrias que pasarle `total` en vez de `mostrarTotal` a la función format.

Comment: Si es lo que yo creia, pero se me queda todo el rato en 0€

Comment: Hace falta saber más cosas entonces: dónde estás tratando de llamar a `format` y cuándo se ejecutan las funciones que has puesto: `pintaContenedor`, `funcionQuitar`, `funcionPoner`... es decir, esas funciones se ejecutan cuando se hace click en algún lado, o al cargarse al documento, etc. Cuanto más código puedas poner se va a entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Te he añadido más código, espero te sirva @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería ser un comentario más que una respuesta, pero necesitaba pegarte el código. He cogido tu código y lo he puesto como snippet y lo puedas ejecutar para probarlo.

Solo he hecho dos cambios:

1. He metido lo del formateo de código en la función mostrarTotal
2. He comentado la línea con `document.getElementById('nadaSeleccionado').style.display='none';` porque estaba tirando un TypeError al no encontrar el elemento con id `nadaSeleccionado`.

Mira a ver si te sirve

```js
var total = 0;

var miListaDeConceptos = [
    { "concepto": "Contenedor 20 pies", "precio": 20000, "Metros": "50" },
    { "concepto": "Contenedor 40 pies", "precio": 30000, "Metros": "100 "}
    ];


    function pintaContenedor(x, el ){

    //document.getElementById('nadaSeleccionado').style.display='none';
    //Valido si esta activado o no
    let ternariaVal=($(x).is(':checked')?functionPoner(x,el):functionQuitar(x,el));
  }
  function functionQuitar(x,el){

    var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[ el ];
    let elegido='#'+el;
    total=total- elemento.precio;
    $( elegido).remove();
    mostrarTotal();
  }
  function functionPoner(x,el){
    var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[ el ];
    $( "#ContenedorElegido" ).append('<div id="'+el+'" class="col-12 listado" data-id="" data-precio="'+elemento.precio+'">'+elemento.concepto+'<span class="pull-right">'+elemento.precio+',00 €</span><div>Metros:<span class="pull-right">'+elemento.Metros+'m<sup>2</sup></span></div></div>' );
    total += elemento.precio;
    mostrarTotal();
  }

function mostrarTotal(){
const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'EUR'
   })
   let totalFormateado = formatterEuro.format(total)
   console.log(totalFormateado);
    $("#htmlTotal").html('<div id="div_total"><span class="palab-total">TOTAL: </span><span class="palab-total2">'+totalFormateado+'</span><div></div></div>');
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pruebacheks">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="cocina=[]" id="20pies" onchange="pintaContenedor(this,0);" />
       <label for="20pies" class="corrigeImgContenedor2"><img src="images/svg/20pies.png" alt="" class="img-fluid corrigeImgContenedor"></label>
       <h4>Módulo de 20 pies</h4>
       </li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="cocina=[]" id="40pies" onchange="pintaContenedor(this,1);" />
        <label for="40pies" class="corrigeImgContenedor2"><img src="images/svg/20pies.png" alt="" class="img-fluid corrigeImgContenedor"></label>
        <h4>Módulo de 40 pies</h4>
        </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="htmlTotal">
  <div id="div_total"><span class="palab-total">TOTAL: </span><span class="palab-total2">0,00 €</span><div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA funciona de forma perfecta! una cosa, los precios que están en el JSON tambien los imprimo, esos se pueden formatear?

Comment: @Miguel supongo que si se podrán formatear, te animo a que lo intentes y si te atascas crees una nueva pregunta con las dudas que te hayan surgido

Comment: Si, estoy en ello. Es la primera vez que trabajo con `JSON` muchas gracias por tu atención